# Define function and image of fat Cantor set

Tags: lebesgue-measure, cantor-set

This construction I found it paper published in $1965$  I think. Here is the way that defined. Let $I=[0,1]$ and define a Cantor set as follows.

$C_1$ obtained from $I$ by taking the open interval at the center $\frac{1}{2}$ with length $\frac{1}{4}$. In general $C_n$ is the union of $2^n$ closed intervals and $C_{n+1}$ is obtained from $C_n$ by taking out of each intervals of these $2^n$ intervals a concentric open interval of length $\frac{1}{2^{2n+2}}$. So, it is easy to see the Lebesgue measure for $C=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} C_n$ is $\frac{1}{2}.$ Now define $f:I\rightarrow I^2$ as follows $$ f(t)=(x(t),y(t))$$ where $x(t)=2m(C\cap [0,t])$ and $y(t)=2x(t)-t$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue  measure. Let $M=f[I]$ and $K=f[C]$.

Here is my question why $K$ is obtained from $M$ by taking out all open vertical and these occur when abscissa is $\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{1}{4}$,$\frac{3}{4}$,$\frac{1}{8}$,...

I did not see why this is case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Andres Do you have any idea why this is true?

Comment: The term "Cantor set" itself refers specifically to Cantor's remove-the-middle-third construction. Sets such as this that remove less are called "Fat Cantor sets".

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x$ is continuous, increasing (but not strictly), and rises from $0$ to $1$. $y(t)$ is also continuous, but is strictly decreasing wherever $x$ is constant. As a result $f$ is one-to-one. Because $f$ is injective, $$M \setminus K = f(I \setminus C)$$
Now $I \setminus C$ consists exactly of all the intervals removed in the construction of $C$. On each of these intervals, $x$ is constant, and $y$ decreases linearly. Thus $f(t)$ is a vertical line segment on these intervals.

<s>When each of these intervals was removed from $C$, at that step, the two intervals left behind were still unbroken, after which they were treated exactly like $I$ itself. In particular, exactly half of their length is removed. Hence when $t$ is the lower endpoint of a removed interval, $x(t) = 2(\frac t2) = t$. So determining the abcissa of these vertical line segments is just a matter of finding the left endpoints of all removed intervals in the construction of $C$.</s>

Finally, one has to show that there are no other vertical line segments, other than when $t$ is in one of the removed intervals. Otherwise, removing vertical segments would remove points from $K$ as well. But the only way to have a vertical segment is for $y$ to change while $x$ is constant, which requires $y$ to change linearly, and therefore over some interval. So $x$ is constant over an interval, which means that the intersection of $C$ and this interval has measure $0$. But from the construction, the only intervals over which $C$ has measure $0$ are subsets of the removed intervals. Therefore no vertical open line segment of $f$ intersects $K$.

Thus $f(I \setminus C)$ consists entirely of vertical open lines segments, and $K$ contains no vertical open line segments. So removing the vertical line segments ($f(I\setminus C) = M \setminus K$) from $M$ leaves $K$.

Comment: Sincclair,Thank you. Is construction of C as follows $C_1=[0,3/8]\cup [5/8,1]$ from $C_2=[0,5/32]\cap[7/32,3/8]\cap[5/8,25/32]\cap[7/32,1]$.So, from where  you get  $1/2$ is endpoints from one removable intervals.

Comment: @Gob. I don't. You produced that list of abcissas, not me. I find the abcissas to be exactly the lower endpoints of removed intervals.

Comment: actually, I just found it the paper as I said. but question is how $\frac{1}{2}$ will be endpoints of intervals because will be removed in the first step

Comment: I going to have to revise this. When $t$ is the lower end of an interval removed at step $n$, then $x(t) = m(C_n \cap [0,t])$, that is, everything below $t$ and still remaining after the $n^{th}$ removal. So while $x(3/8) = 3/8$, we have $x(25/32) = 15/32$. not $25/32$ as I claimed.